# How to store data in sessionStorage?

Tags: socket.io, react-router, google-chrome-devtools, sessionstorage

I want to store the a string in the `sessionStorage` inside the chrome dev tools. 
I specifically want to store the socket.id from socket.io inside the sessionStorage in order to use the same socket.id in my multi-paged web app; is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything in sessionStorage. Session Storage acts like a localstorage. The only difference is the session storage will disapper if you close the tab or browser.

Example code:

```
public setSession(authResult): void {
    // Set the time that the access token will expire at
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
    sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    sessionStorage.setItem('socketId', socket.id); // Save your socket id here 
    sessionStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
  }
```

Pass the socket in constructor and access it in any of your method like above (setSession)

Comment: for a multi-paged web app, how will this allow the socket to persist through different routes? will the socket still disconnect when I go to a different page?